# Set Laravel application online to whole LAN with domain name

Tags: php, apache, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have developed a Laravel 5.4 application and now I want to put it "online" for everyone in my LAN and also set a local domain name to it, like somedomain.lan, for example. When I run `php artisan serve --port=XXXX` it starts the application on localhost port XXXX. Given that I'm running a Linux machine, how to make it available this service on port XXXX in such a way that my whole LAN, and only my LAN (not external internet), sees it and also give the domain name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your command prompt, type "ipconfig", look for your ipv4 address. It should be 192.168.xxx.xxx.

Then php artisan serve --host=[your ipv4 address]

Make other computers connected to your network to connect to your application using your ipv4 address. Your ipv4 address define your computer address within current used network.

Not sure will work or not, but i do it this way and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use [Laravel valet](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/valet)

With `valet` you can say:

`Valet share`

Then you will get a unique link that can be shared.

Super easy I use it everyday!

With artisan you can set the ip like this:

```
php artisan serve --host=503.246.895.41 --port=8125
```